# Problems with showing a dropdown inside a jquery-ui dialog title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-dialog, title

I'm using the Dialog component from the jQuery UI library. I'd like to show a simple dropdown (`<select>`) inside its title bar. The component allows that (any HTML can be placed in the title bar), but it has issues: moving the mouse around in Opera flickers the dropdown a lot and in other browsers (Chrome, IE9) the dropdown cannot be opened.

I've tried adding event handlers to as many events as I could think and canceling bubbling on them. More specifically, I've disabled the following events: onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup, onmouseover, onmouseout, onmouseenter, onmouseleave. This makes it better in Chrome/IE9, but Opera still flickers a lot, so I suppose that something is still wrong. Also, this seems somehow... wrong.

Any ideas on how to get a dropdown working properly in there?

Comment: Can you please post your implementation?

Comment: Here: [http://jsfiddle.net/a9ntp/](http://jsfiddle.net/a9ntp/)

Comment: You do not know what I think. You are not psychic.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing any weird Opera behavior but I see the problem in Chrome with the select not opening. The HTML looks fine and the console shows nothing. It almost feels like a weird z-index or overflow issue but I can't seem to get around it. jQuery/Chrome bug?

Comment: It's the draggable property.  Disable it and the drop down works.  You're going to have to overwrite whatever causes the dialog to drag.

Answer (score 3):

Almost two years late to answer this, but I had the same problem and ended up with a simpler solution that I wanted to share.

The jQuery UI Dialog by default ignores .ui-dialog-content (the content of the dialog) and .ui-dialog-titlebar-close (top right close button in the title element) when dragging. This is done with the following code:

```
this.uiDialog.draggable({
        cancel: ".ui-dialog-content, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close",
        ...
    });
```

This is the same behavior needed for anything that is added to the title element. I was able to add my dropdown to the draggable "cancel list" by using the following code:

```
$(dialog).appendTo('body').showDialog({
            ...
            dialogClass: 'dialog-quick-select',
            open: function(event, ui) {
                var dropdownHtml = '<select id="market-set-dropdown"></select>';
                var $currentDialog = $('.dialog-quick-select');

                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar', $currentDialog).append(dropdownHtml);

                //this is needed to allow the dropdown to be opened.
                $currentDialog.draggable({
                    cancel: '.ui-dialog-content, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close, #market-set-dropdown'
                });
            }
        });
```

I'm adding my dropdown in the open method, which is why I chose to modify cancel there. Also note that my code relies on a custom class name assigned to the dialog, which is set with dialogClass option.

One more note, if the class names pre-defined by the dialog ever change (.ui-dialog-content and .ui-dialog-titlebar-close), the cancel will no longer work on those elements.

API for jQuery UI Dialog: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/a9ntp/13/

I have been messing with it for a few minutes now, and I think I might have a solution for you.  This is the first time I've used fiddle, so if it doesn't work let me know.  As far as I can tell, the issue comes up because the title bar on the dialgo popup is draggable.

```
var popup = $('<div>Hello world!</div>');

$(popup).dialog({title: 'Text <select id="dropDown"><option>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option><option>D</option></select>', draggable: false});

$('#dropDown').hover(
    function(){
        $(popup).dialog('option', 'draggable', true);
    },
    function(){
        $(popup).dialog('option', 'draggable', false);
    }
);
```

When the mouse hovers on the drop down list, it will disable the drag letting you select the object.  When it leaves the drop down list, it should reinitialize the dragging functionality. Hope that helps or at leasts gives you some ideas to work on!!!

Comment: Not bad, worthy of +1. To be honest though, I had already come to that conclusion some time ago. But I do want to keep the draggable behavior, and the Opera weirdness doesn't go away with it. The all-event-cancel-bubble thing works exactly as well, so I guess I'll keep that unless something better comes along. I still don't understand why Opera flickers the dropdown and... well, there are other oddities too. But I suppose that Opera is just my favorite browser, and not really among the target browsers, so I can live with this imperfection.